# Ignore empty fields with serializeArray() method

Tags: jquery

When I run this code, there are several empty fields and passed to the server. How can I avoid empty fields?

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: {serialize_data: $("form").serializeArray()},
        url: "<?php echo $this->serverUrl() . $this->baseUrl(); ?>/admin/examresults/addexamresults/",
        success: function(response) {
            $('#msg').html(response);
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is another way to do it.

Check please:

```
   $("input[value!=''],checkbox[value!=''],radio[value!=''],select[value!='']").serializeArray();
```

regards